# Finding Changed files in a ClearCase folder

Tags: file, clearcase

I have a Folder in ClearCase that contains a large list of Reports.
I have checked all the Reports out because I need to make a sweeping change.
I have changed a set of the Reports and now want to deploy this set.

I probably should have checked the Report files out one at a time and then deployed each as I finished.
But, since I did not do that, is there a way to inspect the ClearCase folder that contains the List of checked out Reports to see which ones have changed and which ones have not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could ask cleartool for a diff with the previous version:

```
 cleartool lsco -r -cvi -fmt "diff -options \"-hea\" -pred \"%n\"\n" | cleartool | grep ">>>"
```

That would give you the list of currently checked-out *modified* files.

Note: remove the '`-r`' option if you only want the check-out files of the current directory (and not its sub-directories)

Comment: @VonC....interesting...thanks. However, I am unable to tell where in the above command I would insert the path to my view. I received the error "Unable to determine the view for '.': not a ClearCase Object"

Comment: @Mike: you need to be in the directory where your Reports are. (meaning you will be within your view). You can right click on the ClearCase folder, and ask for "element properties" in order to copy the full path of that folder in a DOS session.

Comment: @VonC...awesome. I'l give that a try and give a response.... OK I gave that a try and it looks like it returned a list containing all the checked out Reports...not just the ones that have changed. Ideas?  Ah....I just disciovered my error.  I removed the grep piece of the command line.  I am now exexuting  cleartool lsco -r -cvi -fmt "diff -options \"-hea\" -pred \"%n\"\n" | cleartool and it worked great!!!

Answer (score 3):

In ClearCase (or Explorer if you have integration enabled), right-click the base of the tree, and choose "Find Modified Files".  This will return a list of ALL files that have been modified, and that are part of the repo (i.e. it will not return list of private files).

If you want to know all files - checked out, modified, and private - the only way I know of is to use cleartool from within the view:

```
cleartool ls -r
```

If you want more (or less) info about the files, check the docs for the -fmt option (which doesn't work with ls, but does work with describe), and you can create a command that will give you exactly what you want (it'll take some experimenting until you get the hang of it).

NOTE:  "Find Modified Files" is **only** available within the gui from the base of the view tree;  Elsewhere your only option is "Find Checked Out Files" (confusing, to say the least).

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a second view with an identical config spec as the view with the checked out files.  Once you have the second view set up you can compare the same directory in each view with a difference tool (like WinDiff).  This will list all the files that have been changed.

It's not native to ClearCase but it should give the results you are looking for.

Comment: @Brainimus...thanks!  Would I have to setup the second view prior to checking out the files form the initial directory?

Comment: @Mike: if you do that, don't forget to use 2 *dynamic* views, much easier and quicker to set up for this kind if use (file consultation)

Answer (score 0):

I also found a solution.  I selected my ClearCase folder and clicked on "Find Checkouts".  This showed my huge list of Report files that were checked out.  I then selected them all and selected "Check In".  I left the "Check in if identical to previous version" option unchecked.  I then selected "OK" to check in.  All the modifeid files checked in and the un-modified files remained checked out.  This gave me my delta of modified files vs un-modified files.