# Find new files in CLEAR CASE Explorer

Tags: clearcase

Is there anyone who knows a way to find all added files in a CCE view? just to verify that no file is missing before applying label.
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No file missing means some files might be still in checkout mode, but even then, applying a label would be applied on that checkout version (you would need to make sure and checkin them later)

You can list files [still in checkout here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3424814/6309).

A better query would be to list all files with versions more recent than the previous label (assuming base ClearCase here, not UCM)

You can use the date for instance to [list all files with version newer than a date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16054553/6309)

```
ct find -all -type f -version "{created_since(11-apr-2013) && brtype(branch_name)}" -print
```

That way, you will know all added files, and can check if there are any missing before applying a label.

---

The [OP Frimus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11594109/frimus) proposes an alternative solution [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62039577/find-new-files-in-clear-case-explorer/62040918#comment109773345_62040918):

> I resolved the issue by creating an other view with the same config spec,
>   and I compare the two views.

Comment: Thank you VonC , i resolved the issue by creating an other view to with the same config spec and i compare the two views. but thank you for you solution !

Comment: @Frimus THank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.